# Needle problem in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A grid of lines distance $a$ apart and another grid of lines distance $b$ apart are perpendicular, dividing plane into rectangles. A needle of length $l$=min$\{a,b\}$ is thrown at random onto the grid. What is the probability it intersects lines in both grids simultaneously?

I have no idea how to approach such a problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle

Comment: The nicest proofs in the case of Buffon's needle involve a slick linearity-of-expectation based argument. I can't see a similar argument in this case, which seems a shame since the questioner will probably have to resort to integration.

Comment: Have a look at http://archives.math.utk.edu/ICTCM/VOL19/C016/paper.pdf and then report back to us.Also, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Buffon-LaplaceNeedleProblem.html Also, http://www.math.udel.edu/~pelesko/Teaching/Math308_Spring_2006/buffon.pdf

Comment: Have you had a look at those references, Sahiba?

Comment: Yes and I understood Christian's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that the vertical lines are $a$ apart and the horizontal lines $b$ apart, $\ell=a\leq b$. The needle $N$ has a random inclination $\phi$ with repect to the horizontal, whereby we may assume that $\phi$ is uniformly distributed in $\bigl[0,{\pi\over2}]$, making use of symmetry. Given $\phi$, the probability that $N$ intersects a vertical line is ${a\cos\phi\over a}$, 
 the probability that $N$ intersects a horizontal line is ${a\sin\phi\over b}$, and these two events are independent. It follows that the overall probability $P$ that $N$ intersects lines of both kinds is given by
$$P={2\over\pi}\int_0^{\pi\over2}\>{a\cos\phi\over a}{a\sin\phi\over b}\>d\phi={a\over\pi b}\ .$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint. For one set of parallel lines this is Buffon's Needle Problem. There are many solutions on the internet.

That should get you started dealing with two sets of parallel lines.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle

http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/piday/
http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/piday/whypi.pdf